# Backgrounded subshells use incrementally more memory

Tags: bash, subshell

I am starting 1000 subshells in the background in a loop. I assume they use roughly the same amount of memory.

```
for i in `seq 1000`; do
  (
    echo $i;
    sleep 100;
  )&
done;
```

However, they do not. Each new subshell eats up a little bit more memory than the previous one. Their memory usage is increasing.

```
$ ps -eo size,command --sort -size | grep subshell | head -n2
  624 /bin/bash /tmp/subshells.sh
  624 /bin/bash /tmp/subshells.sh
$ ps -eo size,command --sort -size | grep subshell | tail -n2
  340 /bin/bash /tmp/subshells.sh
  340 /bin/bash /tmp/subshells.sh
```

The smallest subshell used 340KB, while the largest one needed 624KB.

What's going on here? Is there a way to avoid this? I'm sad because my parallel computation is organized in a way that it needs thousands of backgrounded subshells, and I'm running out of memory.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing `(...)&` and not `{...}&`. `()` is at best pointless here, and at worst wasting an extra fork.

Comment: also, you really shouldn't use ` in bash. Prefer `$(...)` instead. Bash can also do what seq does natively with either a c-style for loop, or `{1..100}`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Is the code in your question exactly the contents of `/tmp/subshell.sh`? What version of bash are you using? Also: Can you demonstrate that the size is "slowly increasing", as opposed to being random?

Comment: @DTSCode No reason, I'm not great at bash. Thanks for the tips, though. However, the problem reproduces with `{...}&`  with the exact same memory footprint.

Comment: @rici `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. I made a copy-paste mistake and the memory footprint corresponds to `seq 1000`. That's how I know it's increasing as opposed to being random: the more subshells I put in the background, the more memory each subshell requires. I've tried with `seq 4000`, the memory usage per subshell is between 656K and 1772K. 5000 subshells: 748K-2224K. I run out of memory at this point.

Comment: (otherwise it's the exact content or `/tmp/subshells.sh`, without the shebang `#!/bin/bash`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The essential issue here is that when bash starts up a subshell, it just clones itself rather than executing a new shell from scratch. That means that the subshell is born with all the temporary data structures allocated in the parent shell.

Doing it this way is required for the subshell to inherit the current execution environment: shell functions and variables, and other shell settings. It is also generally more efficient, since it avoids the shell startup costs, which are considerable.

Unix copy-on-write (COW) semantics avoid some of the memory costs of duplicating all these data structures. But since COW works on complete pages, not individual allocations, it is not going to be able to completely avoid copies.

One simple thing you can do to reduce memory consumption is to change your `for` loop to a computed `for`, which looks a lot like a C `for` with extra parentheses:

```
for ((i=0; i<5000; ++i)); do
```

Your for loop (`for i in $(seq 5000); do`) has to start by expanding the output of `seq 5000` into a string (of about 30kb) and then splitting it into 5000 words, each of which is a single allocation, as well as a 5000-element vector of pointers. Allocation overhead means that the cost of each word is going to be more than 40 bytes, even though each string is only 5 bytes long. Since these are individual allocations, they get scattered around a bit and other allocations will be made in the same VM pages, triggering COW.

Although these numbers seem small, you are multiplying everything by making N clones of shells with N word vectors, meaning that total memory consumption is quadratic in N. If you have 25 million words, that's going to add up to a lot even if each word only occupies a few bytes: at 40 bytes each, that's a gigabyte. And quadratic growth makes it increase rapidly.

When I tried the change to the `for` statement, it saved (in total) about a third of the used memory.

That's a big win for little effort but it doesn't really address the underlying problem. The parent shell also needs to keep track of all the children it spawns, and it does that by keeping a little data about each child. That memory structure is modified each time a new child is spawned, so each new child is born with a different data structure. In this case, COW doesn't help at all, and the total memory consumption will be strictly quadratic.

Fixing that will depend on what you actually do inside the loop.

As suggested by Charles Duffy in a (now-deleted) comment, a simple fix is to simply remove the parallel task from the job table using the `disown` command:

```
for ((i=0; i<5000; ++i)); do
  (
    echo $i;
    sleep 100;
  )&
  disown
done;
```

On the other hand, if all you are doing is starting up an external command -- or even if that is the last thing you do and everything else is quite fast -- you could use `exec` to replace the subshell memory image with the external command:

```
for ((i=0; i<5000; ++i)); do
  (
    echo $i;
    exec sleep 100;
  )&
done;
```

You could even do the `exec` with a full script, but calling a less memory-intensive shell such as `dash`.

Experimental results (total process size in kilobytes):

```
                             fix for    fix for    fix for
                 Only fix   + disown     + exec     + exec
   N  Original   for loop   children      sleep       dash
4000   4655956    3148792    1601428    1233212    1265224
5000   6768896    4404432    2001428    1541460    1581540
6000   9241116    5837660    2401428    1849692    1897768
7000  12056056    7443052    2801428    2158752    2213992
8000  15235688    9220568    3201428    2466104    2530180
```

It's pretty clear that the first two columns are roughly quadratic in N, and the last three are linear.

I used the following helper to collect those statistics; you can see the precise loop in the various case clauses. For all tests, the number of processes whose size were summed was N+1 (so it includes the driver):

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in 
  o*)
    printf "Original: " >> /dev/stderr
    for i in $(seq $2); do ( echo $i; sleep 10; )& done
    ps -osize=,cmd= | grep '[s]ubshell' | awk '{s+=$1}END{print NR, s}' 1>&2
    sleep 15
    ;;
  f*)
    printf "Fix for loop: " >> /dev/stderr
    for ((i = 0; i < $2; ++i)); do ( echo $i; sleep 10; )& done
    ps -osize=,cmd= | grep '[s]ubshell' | awk '{s+=$1}END{print NR, s}' 1>&2
    sleep 15
    ;;
  d*)
    printf "Also disown: " >> /dev/stderr
    for ((i = 0; i < $2; ++i)); do ( echo $i; sleep 10; )& disown; done
    ps -osize=,cmd= | grep '[s]ubshell' | awk '{s+=$1}END{print NR, s}' 1>&2
    sleep 15
    ;;
  e*)
    printf "Exec external: " >> /dev/stderr
    for ((i = 0; i < $2; ++i)); do ( echo $i; exec sleep 10; )& done
    ps -p$$ -Csleep -osize= | awk '{s+=$1}END{print NR, s}' 1>&2
    sleep 15
    ;;
  a*)
    printf "Exec dash: " >> /dev/stderr
    for ((i = 0; i < $2; ++i)); do ( exec /bin/dash -c "echo $i; sleep 10"; )& done
    ps -p$$ -Cdash -osize= | awk '{s+=$1}END{print NR, s}' 1>&2
    sleep 15
    ;;
  *)
    echo "First argument should be original, forloop, disown, exec or ash."
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Beautiful. Illuminating.